# Architecture Azure AD Resource Groups

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

Please, could you tell me the advantages and disadvantages of using the resources of the Stage and Dev environments in a single Resource Group? As information: Access to these resources is common and the life cycle will be 90% the same. What other critical factors can affect this configuration?

Many Thanks

Comment: @PeterBons. Many Thanks for your response. Do you see any advantage in placing them in separate Resource Group? As information: Access to these resources is common and the life cycle will be 90% the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not many cons in using 2 resource groups for this IMHO. If those 2 rgs are the only ones in the same subscription you can define RBAC at the subscription level so that is one disavantage taken away. There are many  advantages:

- Fine grained access control, seperated by environment.
- Possibility to deploy the resources using ARM/Bicep templates. Even if the life cycle is 90% the same, the 10% can make it hard to use a complete deployement using ARM/Bicep. Also, I strongly recommend a template per environment.
- Apply tags per resource group to create budget/get costs insights

If one of those features listed here might be useful now or in the near future, I wouldn't hesitate to use 2 resource groups.